# Counter example to show that $ s(X) \le d(X) $

Tags: general-topology, cardinals

I am trying to show that there exists a topology in which $ s(X) \le d(X) $.
I am working with the co-countable topology with an infinite topological space X. I understand the $d(X)$ is uncountable and the $ s(X) $ is countable.

For the density, I understand that I have to show that no countable set is dense.

For the spread, I know a little less. I know that I have to take an uncountable subset of X and show the spread is countable in the co-countable topology.

I understand these concepts however I am having trouble writing them on paper.

Any hints and direction would be appreciated!

Comment: If you just want an example where $s(X)\le d(X)$ what's wrong with the real line with the usual topology? Aren't $s(\mathbb R)$ and $d(\mathbb R)$ both equal to $\aleph_0$?

Comment: Yes I mean strictly less than. And the definitions sorry:
$s(X) = sup ( \vert A \vert : A \textrm { is a discrete subset of } X ) $

$d(X) = \min ({ \vert D\vert : \overline{D} = X})$

Comment: You asked this question a few days ago, and I answered it with an example.